# Notepad++ like editor for linux which highlights words on right clicking

Tags: linux, notepad++, text-editors

What I'm looking for is the Notepad++ feature where I can highlight words on right clicking and choosing one of the 5 styles (so that all instances of that word get highlighted with that color), in some editor in linux (Red hat). I find that it helps me in understanding new code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) can do it. Once you've loaded a file, press:

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd> then <kbd>h</kbd> and finally <kbd>r</kbd>

or alternatively if your version of [Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) doesn't recognize the previous shortcut:

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> then type `highlight-regexp` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

[Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) will ask you the regexp (a simple word or phrase will work too) to highlight, then it will ask you the color name too, usually starting with `hi-` e.g. `hi-yellow` (you can use <kbd>Tab</kbd> to complete). That's all.

It may sound complicated but that's [Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/); there are plenty of ways to speed up this process if you want to mess up with it. And I suggest you to do so.

Comment: I have come to the conclusion that all the stereotypes about emacs are, in fact, not stereotypes.

Comment: Yes, it's true. But IMHO Emacs it's the best "text" editor around.

Comment: [C-x M-c M-butterfly](http://xkcd.com/378/)...

Comment: BTW @cYrus, my emacs doesn't seem to believe in that keybinding. What version are you using, and what command is bound that way?

Comment: @dmckee: The command is called `highlight-regexp` (so you can invoke it with `M-x highlight-regexp RET`). The key binding was introduced in Emacs 23, and I think there were other improvements to the highlighting features.

Comment: @dmckee: Gilles already answered you. « Dammit, Emacs. » LOL

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can use [jEdit](http://www.jedit.org/) and the highlight plugin to achieve what you are looking for...

*Highlight:
Highlights words (or matched regexps) with different colors.*

Answer (score 1):

Use [Geany](https://www.geany.org/). It is the best native linux alternative for Notepad++:

> Geany is a text editor using the GTK2 toolkit with basic features of
>   an integrated development environment. It was developed to provide a
>   small and fast IDE, which has only a few dependencies from other
>   packages. It supports many filetypes and has some nice features.

[image]